# Redundant Parentheses in Roslyn SyntaxGenerator AssignmentStatement

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using Roslyn to generate code for a tool I'm building. I'm using the SyntaxGenerator (as opposed to SyntaxFactory) as I'd prefer to not have to write implementations for both C# and VB.NET.

According to the reference source, the [AssignmentStatement](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/CodeGeneration/CSharpSyntaxGenerator.cs,4a7774801c43c306) deliberately adds parentheses to the right side node. E.g.

```cs
Key = (key)
```

Whereas what I'm looking for is without parentheses:

```cs
Key = key
```

**Example**

This is a very basic, very watered down example which should reproduce this behaviour.

```cs
public void Example()
{
    using (var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace())
    {
        var generator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(workspace, LanguageNames.CSharp);

        var statement = generator.AssignmentStatement(generator.IdentifierName("Key"), generator.IdentifierName("key"));

        var result = statement.NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString();
    }
}
```

I've searched extensively both here on SO as well as on Github, Roslyn Reference Source and various blogs and [examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707527.aspx)* but can't seem to find an *elegant* way to remove these redundant parentheses.

Although this is still legal syntax and will compile, it's *really* annoying.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong? Tips? Hopeless case?

*This example generates a constructor with redundant parentheses in the assignments as well.

Comment: Guess you didn't click the link for AssignmentStatement - takes you to that method's implementation (line 3716) with the call to Parenthesize() on line 3718.

Comment: They're an aesthetic annoyance (as mentioned in OP - "Although this is still legal syntax and will compile, it's really annoying.")

Comment: I clicked the link - that's why I knew it was 4000+ lines - but I hadn't waited long enough for my browser to scroll to the location. Mea culpa. I suppose it demonstrates a reason for commenting code.

Comment: The method linked to is an override. The method it overrides is commented. 

As for my example code - thought it was pretty self-explanatory given context of the post/question. My bad.

Comment: The comments in the code don't appear to explain the unqualified addition of parentheses - can you think of a situation where they are *required*? I suppose that it could be faster overall *in general* to add them.

Comment: My guess would be that it's intended to support arbitrary assignment statements and not just (as in my case) constructors. E.g. 

    Value = (21 * 2); 

Even though, strictly speaking, the parentheses aren't _required_ in this case they do improve the readability. 

It would also support direct cast by default. 

Perhaps that (and others I haven't thought of) is the reasoning.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing that behaviour so I'm a little surprised you're getting this. However I have a hunch that you can probably get rid of this by calling the `Simplifier` afterwards?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JeroenVannevel but the `Simplifier.ReduceAsync` method takes `Document` as an argument. This isn't available in a Workspace (as far as I can tell). 

Might have to bite the bullet and do this from `SyntaxFactory`instead.

Comment: @DavidSexton: `Document` is available in a `Workspace`.  You need to create a `Project` and add the syntax tree as a `Document`.  This is because simplification needs semantic information.